# How to check if WordPress website or it's host is hacked? Website is being automatically copied to other site

Tags: wordpress, security, web-scraping, vps

I have a pretty weird problem and I cannot get a hold of it, so I am posting this question here to get some advices.

So the problem goes as follows - I have a website(lets call it mywebsite.com) and then there is this illegally set up website(illegalwebsite.com), which is stealing code and content of my website. Problem is that this illegalwebsite.com is somehow stealing content and code from my website automatically(I did a small test today - posted new class in my HTML code of my website and immediately checked the illegalwebsite.com and the new class was there).

Can someone advise how to block or prevent this? illegalwebsite.com is hiding behind Cloudflare, so I cannot see their host IP.

What have I done so far(nothing has worked):

1. I am using Cloudflare and have enabled content scraping shield, which prevents hot-linking to my websites resources
2. Configured Wordfence plugin to prevent minimum request rates via firewall for website resaurces
3. Contacted Cloudflare, domain registrar, hosting company of illegalwebsite.com to take down their website or at least to get to know their host IP, but without results so far

What else could I do? If somehow I could get to their host IP, I could check the traffic which is going there and try to block it.

Could it be that they are using some auto scrape tools or have hacked my server? I am using DigitalOcean VPS and Runcloud to host my website.

Comment: Are they not proxying instead of copying?

Comment: Could be that they are proxying. How could I check if they are? I am not seeing anything suspicious in web server logs, I am also using Cloudflare, which probably would not allow them to do that, but of that I am not sure.